# Use OAuth 1 Class in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

Hi I want to integrate the Yahoo BOSS API with Symfony2, but the OAuth code class suggested by Yahoo doesn’t seem to work with modern PHP frameworks.

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php

```
/* Generic exception class
 */
class OAuthException extends Exception {
  // pass
}

class OAuthConsumer {
  public $key;
  public $secret;

  function __construct($key, $secret, $callback_url=NULL) {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->secret = $secret;
    $this->callback_url = $callback_url;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return "OAuthConsumer[key=$this->key,secret=$this->secret]";
  }
} [...]
```

http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_php

I think the OAuth class has namespace issues, what steps do I need to take to implement this class in Symfony2?

Comment: You could create it as a service - see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Hi I intend to implement it as a service once I have it working.  Thanks!

Comment: did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a directory like Project/src/**OAuth**

2) Place the classes in separate files inside that directory.

3) Add `namespace OAuth;` at the beginning of every OAuth class.

4) Add a backslash to the Exception class (or add `use Exception;`):

```
class OAuthException extends \Exception
```

5) Avoid underscores in class names ([Laravel-Oauth2 Issue in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332530/laravel-oauth2-issue-in-laravel-4) , [Underscores in Namespaces and Class Names](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)):

```
abstract class OAuthSignatureMethodRSASHA1 extends OAuthSignatureMethod

class OAuthSignatureMethodPLAINTEXT extends OAuthSignatureMethod

class OAuthSignatureMethodHMACSHA1 extends OAuthSignatureMethod
```

6) Fix the array_map call in OAuthUtil:

```
return array_map(array('OAuth\OAuthUtil', 'urlencode_rfc3986'), $input);
```

7) And finally use it:

```
<?php

namespace My\PlaygroundBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use OAuth\OAuthConsumer;
use OAuth\OAuthRequest;
use OAuth\OAuthSignatureMethodHMACSHA1;
use OAuth\OAuthUtil;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $cc_key  = "your consumer key here";
        $cc_secret = "your consumer secret here";
        $url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/news,web,images";
        $args = array();
        $args["q"] = "yahoo";
        $args["format"] = "json";

        $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
        $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);
        $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethodHMACSHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
        $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array($request->to_header());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
        $results = json_decode($rsp);

        return array(
            'results' => $results
        );
    }
}
```

So those are the steps I followed and it worked; you can grab the classes from here: https://github.com/coma/OAuthSOSample

Answer (score 4):

In Symfony 2 I can recommend a third party bundle that will support OAuth 1 & 2.

Take at look: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Comment: Hi I shouldn't need to add a bundle just to access a REST API with OAuth 1, that project has a ton of functionality that I don't need.  Thanks though!

Comment: No one will force you to add this bundle. But you can take a look how it works and take what you need.